# Deduce Symmetry in graph from Kamada-Kawai-layout

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, symmetry

I am analysing a graph and using the networkx Python package I plotted it. The layout I used is the Kamada-Kawai-layout which minizes the Kamada-Kawai cost function. I obtain the following:

[image: Plotted graph]

From looking at it there is some rotational symmetry and I am wondering how to translate this into a formal mathematical observation. What could a possible formulation about a graph property look like?

The graph is the result of the 5-fold Cartesian graph product of the Johnson $J(4,2)$ graph with itself and removing all vertices wich contain non-unique entries, e.g., a vertex of the form $(1,2,1,3,2)$ is removed.

Comment: Do you have the adjacency matrix? You can look at its symmetries.

Comment: Yes, I do for this particular case. How would I deduce symmetries from the adjacency matrix?

Comment: You can look for permutations $P$ such that $PA=AP$. With hundreds of vertices, it's not easy, unless you already have some idea of the symmetry. For example, it looks like there is 6-fold symmetry, so you can try to divide the vertices into 6 subsets that map to each other. It's hard to say more without the actual graph.

Comment: I added a discription of the construction I made to obtain the given graph.